# req.body is an empty object from simple HTML form using express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm getting a req.body back when I submit my HTML form, but it's always an empty object. I'm testing in postman and also submitting the form from the localhost in the browser.

When I log it in the node console, it says [Object: null prototype]

I've read and tried all the (many) proposed solutions to similar things, but none seem to apply.

Thank you very much!

```
// homepage.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="greeting">Sign Up // Sign In</h1>

    <div>
      <form
        action="http://localhost:3000/auth/signup"
        method="POST"
        class="inbox"
        id="sign-up-form-id"
        enctype="text/html"
      >
        <label for="sign-up-name-id">Sign Up: Name</label>
        <br />
        <input
          class="name"
          id="sign-up-name-id"
          name="signUpNameName"
          type="text"
          placeholder="your name here"
          required
        />
        <br />
        <label for="sign-up-password-id">Password</label>
        <br />
        <input
          class="password"
          id="sign-up-password-id"
          name="signUpPasswordName"
          type="password"
          placeholder="create a password"
          required
        />
        <br />
        <input class="btn" id="sign-up-btn" name="sign-up-btn" type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>


    <script src="homepage.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// app.js

const createError = require("http-errors");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const sassMiddleware = require("node-sass-middleware");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");

const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
// import other routers here like:
// const postsRouter = require('./routes/posts');

const app = express();



// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  sassMiddleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    indentedSyntax: false, // true = .sass and false = .scss
    sourceMap: true
  })
);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));




app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/auth", authRouter);
// add more routers here:
// app.use('/posts', postsRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

```
routes/auth.js

const express = require("express");
const { createUser } = require("../controllers/auth-controller");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/signup", createUser);

module.exports = router;
```

```
controllers/auth-controller.js

const User = require("../models/User");

// const seeIt = (req, res) => {
//   // const form = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
//   console.log(req.body);
// };

const createUser = (req, res) => {
  if (req.body) {
    console.log("here: ", req.body);
  }
  User.create(req.body, err => {
    if (err) res.status(500).json({ flash: err.message });
    else res.status(200).json({ flash: "User created!" });
  });
};

module.exports = { createUser };
```

Comment: Why is `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` registered more than once? Same goes for the json parser, you should only register them once.

Comment: thanks @JakeHolzinger, the duplicate was added in while trying the million and one fixes suggested on other similar SO questions - I forgot to take it out. Edited now, thanks for pointing it out. Sadly not related to the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the request is hitting the route that you expect? You have a catch all route (e.g., `app.use("/", ...)`) declared before your more specific route (e.g., `app.use("/auth", ...)`). The order of the routes matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only one reason why you get something like this: `[Object: null prototype]` it's because { extended: false };

‍ Now, you try to change your `extended` to `true`. For an example, you can look at this code below:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
```

> I've been try that code above and it's working fine

I hope it can help you .

Comment: Thanks very much! That's great. Got there in the end!

Answer (score 4):

bodyParser is no longer using by node js

you should use `app.use(express.json());` ONLY, it will takecare all the bodyParser work for you, and below that, write this piece of code ONLY ONCE

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

i noticed that you write above line twice, please write that only once

i hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks Ashir, as per my comment above, those things were only added in at the last minute while trying too many fixes at the same time. I've edited the code now back to how it was when I first come across the problem - sadly it's not fixed.