# Express and nodeJS: [Object: null prototype] { }

Tags: node.js, express

I have this problem, when I receive a request in the server the response is:

`[Object: null prototype] { '{"someParameter": "potatoParameterValue", "someOtherParameter": "otherPotatoParameter}': '' }`

I already used

```
api.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
api.use(bodyParser.json());
```

and that doesn't work,someone else has had the same problem?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, would love some more information about your problem. How do you do your request? Postman or code to start with. Please try to improve your question with as much information and code you think is relevant.

Comment: Can you show us your query as well? Where does this result come from?

Comment: You can read the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994793/req-body-is-an-empty-object-from-simple-html-form-using-express/59996333#59996333

Comment: Does this answer your question? [req.body is an empty object from simple HTML form using express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994793/req-body-is-an-empty-object-from-simple-html-form-using-express)

Answer (score 14):

> The only one reason why you get something like this: `[Object: null prototype]` it's because `{ extended: false };`

‍ Now, you try to change your `extended` to `true`. For an example, you can look at this code below:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
```

> I've been try that code above and it's working fine

I hope it can help you .

Answer (score 1):

Update Express

```
npm i express
```

The new version doesn't need **body-parser**
But you can set **extended** to **true**

Answer (score 1):

ok, first the request was coming from an app in nagular 8 which had an interceptor with a misconfigured header.

this was my header:

`Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8`

was replaced by this:

```Content-Type': 'application/json`

it is important to know this is the default header in case we do not assign a header.

then in the back, we started to receive an empty object, after that we just used

`app.use(bodyParser.json());`

and voilà, that was the solution to the problem.

Thank you all for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try a fast ball, would love some more information..

It looks like you might be missing a " after otherPotatoParameter. Right now the key in the object is the object..

```
{ 
'{"someParameter": "potatoParameterValue", "someOtherParameter": "otherPotatoParameter}': '' 
}
```

Maybe it should be something like this?

```
{
  "someParameter": "potatoParameterValue", 
  "someOtherParameter": "otherPotatoParamete"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
```

or

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

its working in my case

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

// app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use('/',(req ,res ,next) => {

console.log('In the Another Middleware');
    // res.send('<title>Node Learning</title><h1>Hello From Express JS!</h1>');
    next();
})

app.use('/add-product',(req ,res , next) => {
   console.log('In the Another Middleware');
    res.send('<form method="POST" action="/product"><input type="text" name="title" /> 
 <button type="submin">Add</button></form>');
})
app.use('/product',(req , res , next) => {
   console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.use('/',(req ,res , next) => {
    console.log('In the Another Middleware');
    res.send('<title>Node Learning</title><h1>Hello From Express JS!</h1>');
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)